# How to make a tube or pipe as vertical bar graphs in html5 canavs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

A simple Bar Graph like this:

[image]

How do I draw pipes or tubes to replace the grey bars in the bar graph above? The pipes could look closely similar to the pipe image below:

[image]

Specifically, I need to have defining edges or borders (like the one in the pipe image) but I would also need it to have transparency, and maybe lighting or shadow effects, at the front to show the pipe to be hollow.

Comment: SVG of course, you need to draw 2 shapes and animate the inside shape between 0% and 100% along its path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the raised-side bar using simple rectangular fills, strokes & shadows.

- Outside border: a lighter gray
- Raised side border: a darker version of your desired hue
- Inside shadow: a darker gray
- Inside fill: a lighter version of your desire hue

And add a black `context.fillRect` as a value indicator for the bar.

[image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.fillStyle='lightgray';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);

bar(50,50,25,200,'rgb(106,126,152)','rgb(176,196,222)',4);

function bar(x,y,width,height,bordercolor,insidecolor,borderwidth){
    // outside border
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.fillStyle='rgb(180,180,180)';
    ctx.rect(x-2,y-2,width+4,height+4);
    ctx.fill();
    // inside border & inside fill & shadow
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.fillStyle=insidecolor;
    ctx.strokeStyle=insidecolor;
    ctx.lineWidth=borderwidth;
    ctx.rect(x,y,width,height);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.shadowColor='rgb(50,50,50)';
    ctx.shadowBlur=6;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to clip the top part so it looks like it has an opening?

Comment: @junerockwell Sure. Just use `context.clearRect` to snip off the top of the bar.

Comment: clearRect() works. Thanks. One more thing, is there a way to make the outer rectangle look glass-like?

Comment: Glass is invisible :-p ... but glass is often represented by an overlay of almost-transparent white that does not over the entire bottom layer. Perhaps a circle with `fillStyle=rgba(255,255,255,0.15)` and `x=BarX-barWidth*2` and `y=BarY-BarHeight/2.5` and  `radius=barHeight`. This mostly transparent circle would be drawn inside the clipped area. A slightly wider bar is better to show more of the semi-arc. Here's a [sample result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/glassEmbossedBarChart.png) Good luck with your project!